# Redirection issue with angular application static web site hosted in Amazon S3 bucket with OKTA Authorization grant with PKCE flow

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, openid-connect, okta

I have hosted angular 9 app on Amazon S3 as static website hosting and integrated with a OIDC authentication provider (OKTA) and Authorization grant with PKCE flow.

App is deployed successfully and when I click Login, my app gets redirected to okta for login, but when OKTA redirects using implicit/callback, my browser throw following error-

```
404 Not Found
Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: implicit/callback
```

I have also used CloudFront to redirect http to https.

My application setup is:

1. Angular app build and uploaded to Amazon S3
2. S3 static website hosting
3. Cloud Front Distribution for S3
4. Hosted domain(Route 53) to CloudFront

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Gary!

I was able to resolve this issue by following steps:

1. Wrote redirection rules in S3 bucket -

   403
           
           
             index.html
           
         
         
           
             404
           
           
             https
             www.mydomain.com
             #!/
2. Updated the CloudFront behavior to forward the query strings by Selecting "Forward all, cache based on all" in CloudFront behavior for "Query String Forwarding and Caching"
3. Updated the Error document to index.html in CloudFront "Error Pages" for 403 and 404.
4. Adding following JavaScript to index.html file

```js
<body>
  <script>
      var hash = window.location.hash;
      const newHashpath = hash.replace("#!/",""); //(/#!(\/.*)$/.exec(window.location.pathname) || [])[1];
      if (newHashpath) {
        // history.replace(path);
        window.history.pushState({},'',newHashpath);
      }
    </script>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

It feels like S3 is serving the wrong file here, rather than your index.html file, when the login response is received.

**UNDERSTAND THE LOGIN RESPONSE URI**

This will be a value such as the following, and you need to make this serve your index.html file:

- https://web.mycompany.com/myapp/callback?code=abc&state=123

**WORKING CODE SAMPLE**

You can login to my [Online Cloudfront SPA](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/) to compare to a similar SPA that works (mine is coded with ReactJS).

In my case the registered redirect URI is this and includes a trailing backslash to prevent an S3 redirect that loses the login response query parameters:

- https://web.authsamples.com/spa/

A full login response looks like this:

- https://web.authsamples.com/spa/?code=abc&state=123

**DEFAULT DOCUMENT**

This is usually specified as index.html in S3 settings, though you can customise it further via a lambda edge function - see my links to visual blog posts below.

**DEFAULT DOCUMENT SHOULD HANDLE THE LOGIN RESPONSE**

I always process login responses as part of the main index.html page load - see the call to handleLoginResponse in [this source file](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/app/app.tsx). You would need to do the equivalent thing in Angular.

**FURTHER INFO**

Maybe browsing my blog posts below will provide some useful further info - hopefully some of this detail helps you to solve your problem:

- [Code Sample Overview](https://authguidance.com/2019/04/07/local-ui-setup/)
- [Web Cloud Deployment / OAuth Settings](https://authguidance.com/2018/12/02/spa-content-deployment/)
- [Lambda Edge Default Document Customisation](https://authguidance.com/2020/07/21/lambda-edge-spa-extensions/)